# I can't load my trained h5 model with load.models(), how do I fix this error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

So I think tensorflow.keras and the independant keras packages are in conflict and I can't load my model, which I have made with transfer learning.
Import in the CNN ipynb:

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
print(tf.__version__)
```

Loading this pretrained model

```
base_model = keras.applications.xception.Xception(weights="imagenet",
                                              include_top=False)
avg = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
output = keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(avg)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
```

Saving with:

```
model.save('Leavesnet Model 2.h5')
```

Then in the new ipynb for the already trained model (the imports are the same as in the CNN ipynb:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model =load_model('Leavesnet Model.h5')
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-77ca5a1f5f24> in <module>()
      2 from keras.models import load_model
      3 
----> 4 model =load_model('Leavesnet Model.h5')

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in placeholder(shape, ndim, dtype, sparse, name)
    539         x = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    540     else:
--> 541         x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    542     x._keras_shape = shape
    543     x._uses_learning_phase = False

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

I think there might be a conflict between tf.keras and the independant keras, can someone help me out?

Comment: By the way: I'm using Google Colab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a conflict between `tf.keras` and `keras` packages, you trained the model using `tf.keras` but then you are loading it with the `keras` package. That is not supported, you should use only one version of this package.

The specific problem is that you are using TensorFlow 2.0, but the standalone `keras` package does not support TensorFlow 2.0 yet.

Comment: Is there a way I can still import the model? Right now the only way i can get it to work is by saving the weights as a .h5, downloading the base model again and loading the weights: `base_model = keras.applications.xception.Xception(weights="imagenet",
                                                  include_top=False)`, then `model.load_weights('model.h5')`

Comment: @Monlist you need to load your model with tf.keras.models.load_model

Comment: Okay nice, that fixed it for me!

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace

```
from keras.models import load_model
model =load_model('Leavesnet Model.h5')
```

with

`model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)`

It works for me, and I am using:
tensorflow version: 2.0.0
keras version: 2.3.1

You can check the following:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model?version=stable

Answer (score 0):

I think downgrading your **keras** or **tensorflow** will not be that much suitable because you need to retrain your model for various dependencies. Why not try to load the weights instead of loading the model?
here is a piece of code

```
import tensorflow as tf

{your code here}

#save the weights
model.save_weights('model_checkpoint')
#initialise the model again (example - MobileNetv2)
encoder = MobileNetV2(input_tensor=inputs, weights="imagenet", include_top=False, alpha=0.35)
#load the weights
encoder.load_weights('model_checkpoint')
```

and you are good to go